# How to apply filters in dynamodb getItem

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want to fetch specific item from `dynamoDB` by using `table.getItem(xxx)` and while fetching the item  need to apply some filters.

`select * from emp where empid=1 and isadmin=true;`

How can I write above query in dynamo-db.

Below is the sample code which I have tried:

```
GetItemSpec spec = new GetItemSpec()
.withPrimaryKey("empid", "1", "deptno", "12");
 Item outcome = table.getItem(spec);
  System.out.pritnln("outcome "+outcome);
```

In above code I want to apply one more filter like "isAdminU=true"
please give me some suggestions to  add filters in getItem(....).

**Note:**

I am able to resolve my use by using table.query(spec) But this method is returning collections I have to parse and get the first item every time which is not required in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed, DynamoDB's `GetItem` operation does **not** accept a filter. It always returns a single item if it exists, so often there is no need for such filtering. But if you really do want such filtering - e.g., your items are large and you don't want to waste network bandwidth on sending them if they don't pass your filter - as you suggested yourself, you can use a `Query`.

Yes, `Query`'s response format is a little different from `GetItem`, but any DynamoDB library in any language makes getting the first (and only) item in the response trivial. If you're worried about the possibility of getting more than the first item, you can always set `Limit=1` but this isn't necessary if your key condition ensures just one item will match.

You should know that regardless of whether you do an unconditional `GetItem` and filter in the client or do a `Query` with a filter at the server side, in both cases the read cost will be the same as the entire item will be read from disk in both cases. The only - small - difference may be in the network bandwidth costs, and this only becomes relevant if the items are large.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify filter in the GetItem API call in the DynamoDB.

It just supports the projection, for example:

```
GetItemSpec spec = new GetItemSpec()
    .withPrimaryKey("Id", 206)
    .withProjectionExpression("Id, Title, RelatedItems[0], Reviews.FiveStar")
    .withConsistentRead(true);
```

However, there is a QuerySpec API, which can be used to get an item with filter condition in the DynamoDB.

```
 Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("test");

        QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("apartId = :v_id")
                .withFilterExpression("apartName = :apartName")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                        .withString(":v_id", "123")
                        .withString(":apartName", "somewhere")
                        );

        ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);

        Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
        Item item = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            item = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(item.toJSONPretty());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay...yes I agree..we can use query spec in my post also i have mentioned that ..but here I always get only one item if I used queryspec i have to loop it and get the item..that why i am looking into getItem API which return only one  item every time.